# Is there a way to replace the diff utility, with another, non-Tcl/Tk diff utility?

Tags: version-control, cvs

I'm using TkCVS as the GUI front-end for a CYGWIN CVS client, on a Windows XP machine.
It's a good compromise, since on my Linux machine I'm also running TkCVS (the same machine running the CVS server, BTW...).

I'm interested in replacing the diff utility (which has a tkdiff.tcl GUI front-end, for TkCVS) with a commercial product (like BeyondCompare or ExamDiff...)

Does anyone have a way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From a [tkcvs faq](http://www.twobarleycorns.net/tkcvs/FAQ):

> Q4. Can I use a diff tool other than
>   tkdiff with tkcvs?
>
> A. Yes, by changing cvscfg(tkdiff). 
>   You usually have to write a wrapper
>   for    your diff tool to get it to
>   check out the versions, and and deal
>   with its    particular command-line
>   options, which are probably different
>   from tkdiff's.
>
> In the contrib directory, there is
>   a gvim-wrapper called "cvsdiff" which
>   can    be used as-is or as a model for
>   wrapping your favorite diff tool.

Answer (score 0):

what about just using the cvs diff command?

Or download the cvscommand plugin module for vim.